# How can a GMail file attachment of "unknown" file type be downloaded in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, files, downloads, webapps, gmail

How can an e-mail attachment of arbitrary file type be downloaded in Ubuntu Touch? I have a file (say `.dat`, or something the system doesn't recognise) that is an attachment to an e-mail opened in the default GMail application on Ubuntu Touch 15.04 OTA-11. When I select the attachment, I am presented with the message "Sorry, there aren't currently any apps installed that can handle this type of content."

Given that I want to download the file as opposed to open it and given that `wget` or similar is not an option because of authentication limitations, how can this attachment be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to your gmail account from the **browser app** (instead of gmail webapp or Dekko), you'll see an option to simply download the file (along with opening with another app).

There is a [feature request](http://pad.lv/1560086) at Launchpad to include an option to download arbitrary file types from the webapps.